# AWS Cloud9 IDE - app with multiple subdomains

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud9-ide, cloud9, aws-cloud9

I'm builing an app that will use subdomains with Cloud9 IDE. Is there a way to run the app in AWS Cloud9 while having my own subdomains?
For example `https://blog.e7f0178901ad43958f94db7f61a2a8b3.vfs.cloud9.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/`

[image]

I see there is an option to configure a preview url , but I'm not sure how to configure it the right way:

[image]